# How to fix atp0000 error, I receive when build a project?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using axml designer to  build UI. I separate screen on 4 parts of relativeLayout. One I want to locate between another 2 and when add layout_above = "@id/myBottomView" I receive compile error(see below). But designer drawing everything right.
how I can fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#1212ed"
        android:id="@+id/view1">
    </View>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/historyButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="History" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="eFinder"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/libraryButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:text="Library" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addScanView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:layout_above="@id/myBottomView">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scanCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="10/5 scans"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addScansButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Scans"
            android:layout_below="@id/scanCounter"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="9.0dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/addScansButton"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Tap to find E"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myBottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="share" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:text="options" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This what show me designer and it is right but have build error:

[image]

I receive error: //Resources/layout/Main.axml(0,0): Error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/myBottomView'). (APT0000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your RelativeLayout (`myBottomView`) element **above** the element (`addScanView`) that is referencing it, the layout is analyzed top-to-bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myBottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp">
    </RelativeLayout>    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addScanView"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:layout_above="@id/myBottomView">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```